# What is the base frame in velodyne's transform_nodelet?

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to transform the Velodyne LIDAR data before publishing it as a point cloud.

If I understand correctly the purpose of [TransformNodelet](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_pointcloud?distro=groovy) in velodyne package is exactly this. In order to perform this transformation I have to publish a new frame that will be used by the TransformNodelet. For example:

rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 /what_is_this /my_frame 500

My problem is I do not know what is the base frame. Do anybody know what is its name?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68629/what-is-the-base-frame-in-velodyne%27s-transform_nodelet?/) by [Gabor Meszaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2093/gabor-meszaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame ID of the device is determined by the `frame_id` parameter passed to the driver. The default is `/velodyne`, but you can set it however you like.

The `frame_id` parameter passed to the transform nodelet (or node) sets the frame ID into which the data will be converted. The default is `/odom`, which is the ROS convention recommended by [REP-0103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#odom) for mobile platforms. You can set that however you like, as well.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gabor Meszaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2093/gabor-meszaros/) on 2013-07-25**:
Thank you, it works now. I also had to fix something in the code. I will create a patch as soon as possible.
Update: Fixed.

**Comment by [Braad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27680/braad/) on 2016-08-04**:
Thanks. I joined this group to say you thank you. Where can i see the frame id for velodyne? I never could found that.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-08-04**:
If  you look at the `header.frame_id` of any message published, that is the one the driver was configured to use.